# Spy on a local function Angular Service

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, angular-services, spy, spyon

I have an Angular Service using a local function and doing the following work:

```
function myService($http,$q){

var myService = {};

var _localService = function (Table) {
    return Table.something;
}

var _getSomething = function () {
    return _localService('someTable');
}

var _getSomethingElse = function () {
    return _localService('someTable2');
}

myService.getSomething  = _getSomething ;
myService.getSomethingElse  = _getSomethingElse ;

return myService ; }
```

Now i want to test my service with jasmine and i want to  test if localService have been called.
Something like this:

```
spyOn(myService,"_localService");
myService.getSomething();
expect(myService._localService).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

How can i do that, please help.

Comment: Have you made any concrete attempts towards this goal thus far that you can share with us?

Comment: i tried to call localService in this way adding key "this" :

`var _getSomething = function(){
   this._localService('someTable')
}`

doesn't work :(
jasmine does not find localService as Service's attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expose `_localService` in your service or else the spy can't find it.

Because in fact you made it private by returning myService without a `_localService` function.

So you can keep it private, or make it public, if it's public, it will work as is.

If you want to keep it private, then,

you shouldn't test private function, instead test what you expect as a result to the call of the public function. It will allow to refactor inner implementation and still have test to check that your code works.